# Drupal 8 - simple fb connect fails

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, drupal, drupal-8

So i'm developing a Drupal 8 site and I'm using the '**simple fb connect**' module.
I've almost literally copied the code from Drupal to add a custom role to my new user and to get the facebook data and link them to my custom fields. Everything works fine until I actually try to register or login.

First let me explain how the flow works, so when you try to log in or register, you get redirected to the '/management' page ( This with the module '**Redirect after login**' module). This page is only allowed for users with the role **jobseeker**. All this works perfectly fine with the drupal login and registration. Only with the facebook module, something goes wrong.

Judging by my **log messages** this is what happens when I try to login with the simple fb connect module.

1. The session opens normally, if the user hasn't already have an account, it makes a new one. **The user already has the role 'jobseeker' assigned**.
2. There's a **redirect to the page '/management'** (everything is fine up until here)
3. The page '/management' gets an error '**Access Denied**', if I check my logs, drupal tries to access this page as an **anonymous user**... even though the user is logged in.
4. When **refreshing the page**, suddenly i'm logged in and have the role **jobseeker assigned**

This problem occurs not every time and at very random moments, sometimes after 3 login attempts and sometimes after 8.. Can someone help me figure out how I suddenly lose my user's role or how to avoid this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

The module "**Simple fb connect**" conflicts with the module "**Redirect after login**". So I removed the module "**Redirect after login**" and just added the "**Rules**" module, to set my login-destination with a rule.